# Can multiple phone numbers be added to a Google Place?

Tags: google-maps

When adding a Place to Google Maps, there's a place to enter only 1 phone number.

But what if the place has more than one? Is there any way to mention more than one phone number?

[image: Adding a Place to Google Maps]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one place to enter a phone number to via a community edit.

It is possible to enter more than one phone number when you claim the business, but only the primary number will be displayed. To add additional phone numbers, you will need to sign in to [Google My Business](https://business.google.com/?skipLandingPage=true&gmbsrc=ww-ww-et-gs-z-gmb-v-z-h%7Ebhc-core-u%7Cmyb) and have verified or claimed the location.

This is confirmed by Google:

- [Edit your business listing on Google](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3039617?hl=en-GB):

> **Phone**
>
> In addition to your primary business phone number, you can enter up to two more phone numbers (mobile or landline only, no fax).

Comment: So volunteers who just suggest a place without owning it can't do it at all?

Comment: @LWC no they can’t

Comment: What kind of decision is that. Why would they limit it to just one? wtf